# Issue in passing an array to an index in Series object(TypeError: len() of unsized object)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data as ndarray

```
a = [0,1,0,1,2,2]

b = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6']
```

Then I tried:

```
univals = set(a)
serObj=pd.Series()

for ele in univals:
    indexfound=np.where(a == ele)
    Xpointsfromindex=np.take(b, indexfound)
    serobj1=pd.Series(Xpointsfromindex[0],index=ele)   ##error happening here
    serObj.apend(serobj1)
print(serObj)
```

I expect output to be like

```
0    ['x1','x3']
1    ['x2','x4']
2    ['x5','x6']
```

But it is giving me an error like "`TypeError: len() of unsized object`"

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe here is possible create `DataFrame` if same length of lists and then create `lists` with `groupby`:

```
a = [0,1,0,1,2,2]
b = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
print(df)
   a   b
0  0  x1
1  1  x2
2  0  x3
3  1  x4
4  2  x5
5  2  x6

serObj = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)
print (serObj)
a
0    [x1, x3]
1    [x2, x4]
2    [x5, x6]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to stick to what OP was doing, here is the full code that works -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = [0,1,0,1,2,2]
b = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6']

univals = set(a)
serObj=pd.Series()

for ele in univals:
    indexfound=np.where([i==ele for i in a])
    Xpointsfromindex=np.take(b, indexfound)
    print(Xpointsfromindex)
    serobj1=pd.Series(Xpointsfromindex[0],index=[ele for _ in range(np.shape(indexfound)[1])])   ##error happening here
    serObj.append(serobj1)

print(serObj)
```

**Output**

```
[['x1' 'x3']]
[['x2' 'x4']]
[['x5' 'x6']]
```

**Explanation**

`indexfound=np.where(a == ele)` will always return `False` because you are trying to compare a `list` with a scalar. Changing it to list comprehension fetches the indices

The next change is using list comprehension at the `index` parameter of the `pd.Series`.

This will set you on your way to what you want to achieve